# Retrieving unique object list from one to many database relationship query using ResultSet and HashMap

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a traditional one to many relational database model where I have a User and that User can have 0 to many purchases:

**User**

```
id bigint primary key
name varchar(100)
```

**Purchase**

```
id bigint primary key
user_id references user(id)
total float
tax float
date_of_purchase timestamp
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    u.id as "user_id",
    u.name as "user_name",
    p.total as "purchase_total"
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN purchase p 
    ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.date_of_purchase (between dates)
```

So the query returns something like this:

```
1, John Smith, 5.99
1, John Smith, 5.99
1, John Smith, 12.72
2, Sam Carter, 1.99
2, Sam Carter, 22.52
3, Jane Doe, 7.82
```

What I need to return to my business layer is a collection of User objects:

```
List<User> allUsers = getAllUserPurchases(Date from, Date to)

User (id: 1, name: John Smith, List<Purchases>: {.... one for each row ....}
```

So right now, what I am doing is this:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    HashMap<long, User> allUsers = new HashMap<long, User>();
    Purchase purc = null;

    try {
        conn = ... get conn ...;
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(myQuery);
        ps.setDate(1, from);
        ps.setDate(2, to);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            long id = rs.getLong("user_id");

            if(!allUsers.containsKey(id)) {
                ... logic to create user
                ... Take the purchase object, instatiate it, add it to the purchase list for the User object
                ... Add everything to map
            }
            else {
                ... take the purchase for the row, update the User object for the existing map key
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            if(ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if(rs != null) {
                rs.close;
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return allUsers;
```

This will work, but I feel like it's not a very efficient way of doing this. Is there a better way to do this? What is the "accepted standard" for whatever this scenario is called?

I haven't done a large scale query yet, but I suspect performance won't be ideal for a larger to and from date scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks fine. A couple things I would consider:

Java-side: The only thing I would change, based on your requirements (returning a list of Users), is to return allUsers.values(), since you only want a list of the Users, not the whole map. But I'm sure you're doing something along these lines already.

<s>SQL-side: Consider moving your where clause to your JOIN. I believe this will reduce the JOIN time. As in:</s>

```
SELECT
    u.id as "user_id",
    u.name as "user_name",
    p.total as "purchase_total"
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN purchase p 
    ON p.user_id = u.id
    AND p.date_of_purchase (between dates)
```

EDIT: Did some testing with this sql change, and not sure that's actually how it works, crossing out.